# How to make 2 buttons in a row and 2 in a column in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

I have 4 buttons in radio group and want to have 2 buttons in the first row next to each other and 2 in the other row.

I tried putting orientation horizontal attribute on radio group but it made all 4 buttons on the same row

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Iamb"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="false"
            android:text="Trochee" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:text="Dactyl" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Anapest"
            android:freezesText="true"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Put your buttons in GridLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this ? If it is not important whether Relative or not, this design fits perfect... hope it helps...

you can change the button places , and you can covert relative layout to linear layout as well...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="454dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lineartwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:freezesText="false"
                android:text="Trochee" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_button1"
                android:layout_width="89dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:text="Iamb" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:text="Anapest" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_button3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:text="Dactyl" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this class: https://gist.github.com/saiaspire/a73135cfee1110a64cb0ab3451b6ca33
Copy this class to your package and use RadioGridGroup like a GridLayout

```
<yourpackage.RadioGridGroup android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:rowCount="3"
                    android:columnCount="3">
            <RadioButton
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Iamb"
                    android:freezesText="true"/>

            <RadioButton
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:freezesText="false"
                    android:text="Trochee" />



            <RadioButton
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_row="1"
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:freezesText="true"
                    android:text="Dactyl" />

            <RadioButton
                    android:layout_column="2"
                    android:layout_row="2"
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Anapest"
                    android:freezesText="true"/>
        </yourpackage.RadioGridGroup>
```

Comment: This completely broke the code. Now I can select all 4 options at once and the program does not see any options selected.